# How to split a string by another string if it is surrounded by specific characters

Tags: python, regex, split

For example I have:

```
string = 'ST8*010A1~BHT*0019*0 BHT#5*20190114*'
```

I need to split it by "BHT" only if the character before is "~" and the character after is non-numeric and non-alphabetic and not a space.

I tried this:

```
new_list = []
new_list = re.split(r'[~]BHT[^A-Za-z0-9 ]', contents)
```

The issue is that it gives this:

```
new_list = ['ST8*010A1', '0019*0 BHT#5*20190114*']
```

I need:

```
new_list = ['ST8*010A1~', '0019*0 BHT#5*20190114*']
```

Is there a way to rewrite the code, so it keeps "~"?

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may use

```
new_list = re.split(r'(?<=~)BHT[^A-Za-z0-9 ]', contents)
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/zjPgRg) yielding `['ST8*010A1~', '0019*0 BHT#5*20190114*']`.

Here is a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/8FE3tX/1). The `(?<=~)` pattern is a positive lookbehind that only checks for a `~` presence in the string, but it is not consumed, and thus remains in the split chunks.

Comment: That's perfect! Thank you!